# web service java ee 7

Tags: java, web-services

I am creating a Currency converter web service which works like a calculator. I have below code in my service class.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculadoraWebService")
public class CalculadoraWebService {


    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Calculadora")
    public BigDecimal operation(@WebParam(name = "Corvesion") BigDecimal bolf) {
        double bols;
        String op;
        op = String.valueOf(bolf);
        bols = Double.parseDouble(op) / 1000;
        long partent = (long) bols;
        double partdec = bols - partent;
        if (partent ==0 && partdec < 0.750){
            partdec=0.500;
        } else if (partent ==0 && partdec >0.750){
            partdec=1;}
        BigDecimal v1;
        BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(partdec);
        BigDecimal v3 = new BigDecimal(partent);
        v1 = v2.add(v3);
        v1 = v1.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        DecimalFormatSymbols simbolo=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        simbolo.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        simbolo.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##",simbolo);
        BigDecimal resul = new BigDecimal(formato.format(v1));
        return resul;
    }
}
```

When I call above webservice I am getting below error in log. What could be possible cause of this error ?

```
WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details
Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:342) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:157) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) at .....
```

Comment: "Refer to the server log for more details". Please share how you are calling your webservice.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not answer before, now just i'm make a test web service in the netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably be getting a number format exception, 
you need to switch the ',' and '.' in your simbolo definitions.

btw, why do you need the decimal formating since you are returning a BigDecimal ? why not just return v1.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer! Sorry for not answer before,i need the decimal formating because i'm from venezuela and the format here is different, the comma is for decimals, how i do that number format exception.

Comment: I understand the need, I am from Greece and we do use the comma for decimals, but your webservice implementation accepts a BigDecimal and returns a BigDecimal, so there is no need to play around with decimal formating. Quick tip: surround with try catch and log any exception or print the full stack trace to figure out what is the problem (on the server side). I usually wrap all my WS responses in another object that carries messages (in case of exceptions). Perhaps a: MyServiceResponse{ String errorMessage, BigDecimal result } would be more appropriate.